# Find $r$ in the next formula

Tags: polynomials, roots

Lets suppose I have the next values

$$0, 7, 8, 5, 6$$

And the next formula

$$4250 = \frac{0}{(1+r)} + \frac{7}{(1+r)^2} + \frac{8}{(1+r)^3} + \frac{5}{(1+r)^4} + \frac{6}{(1+r)^5}.$$

What is the easiest way to find the $r$?

I need a formula that supports $n$ values

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: Is $4250$ picked at random or is it always $4250$ ?

Comment: That can also change.

Comment: Easiest, not horribly inefficient, way to find $r$ would be to use a binary search.  I'm assuming that $r$ is an interest rate and the payments are all non-negative.

Comment: Yeah, is actually the IRR formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you, please, describe your question in more details? You can use any iterative procedure to solve it... You could use Newton-Raphson, for example. You need an algorithm, is that right?

You can define your functions as:

$$
g(r) = -b + \sum _{i = 1} ^N a_{i}(1 + r)^{-c_{i}}
$$

$$
g'(r) = \frac {dg}{dr} = \sum_{i=1}^N -c_ia_i(1+r)^{-(c_i+1)}
$$

The Newton-Raphson algorithm is as follows:

$$
r_{j+1} = r_j + \frac{g(r_j)}{g'(r_j)}
$$

In the present case, N = 5, $a_i$ = {0, 7,8,5,6} , $a_i$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and b = 4250.

Comment: Yes, i need an easy to use algorithm. I am not very good at math. I need an algorithm to be used inside my application.

Comment: Ok... Are the coefficients and the powers fixed numbers or are they random numbers?

Comment: Just added the algorithm for a more general case. If you are programming the algorithm, you can define g and g' as separate functions, with N (number of samples), $a_i$ (coefficients), $c_i$ (powers) and r as input data.

Comment: By the way, NR gives ONLY one root and it depends on the initial guess for $r_0$.